# The request does not contain a \"file\" part or \"metadata\" part

Tags: mule, httprequest, attachment, mule-studio, mule-esb

I have gone through number of forums including the current forum as well, but I couldn't find concrete answer.

Problem Description: Mule sub flow expects JSON (Content-Type=application/json) as input. An attachment with input JSON, should be sent across with http request to third party REST Service.

Following is the source code used. 
[Sourcecode of Mule subflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMdVK.png)
But the third party REST service is responding with Bad request with error message as "code": 400,. "error": "The request does not contain a \"file\" part or \"metadata\" part. However when tried with Postman, the request was successful as shown below
[Request successful in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Y4DJ.png)
what is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1):

First, do not specify the `Content-Type` since the multipart format requires a special boundary section. The proper header will be generated for you once an attachment is present in the Mule Message. If you hard code it, you will have problems.

Second, if the attachment is suppose to be a JSON, then put `application/json` as the attachment `contentType` instead of `application/octet-stream`.

Third, if the problems persists I would suggest enabling HTTP wire logging (`<AsyncLogger name="org.mule.module.http.internal.HttpMessageLogger" level="DEBUG"/>`) to actually compare the Postman and Mule requests.